# Calculate Time Difference in Visual Basic

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a date/time field in a database table, i want to calculate the time difference between the date/time in table and the current date/time

For example: i want to show in the vb forum 2 Days 10 Hours Remaining

If it doesnt work for both time and date, how to do it for date only?

Thank You

Comment: Are you looking to do this in code, or via a SQL command?  If you want to do it in the code, do you already have the data loaded into a `Date` (`DateTime`) object, or do you need help doing that too?

Comment: I am looking to do it in a code, and yes the data is loaded into the object

Answer (score 3):

If you load the have the data already loaded into a `Date` (`DateTime`) object, then you can just do it like this:

```
Dim loadedDate As Date = ...
Dim span As TimeSpan = Date.Now - loadedDate
Console.WriteLine("{0} Days {1} Hours Remaining", span.Days, span.Hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in the database,

```
SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '2012-12-04T20:00:00')
```

You can replace the hard coded date and time with a datetime column.